# FCKeditor does not show Arabic content

Tags: php, arabic, fckeditor

I had run FCKeditor successfully before I upgraded php version to PHP 5.4. The problem is that editor couldn't display Arabic content. It appears empty, FCKeditor just appears English version, this how I call the editor:

```
<?php
include("editor/fckeditor.php") ;
$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('body') ;
$oFCKeditor->BasePath   = 'editor/' ;
$oFCKeditor->Value      = @$frm['body'] ;
$oFCKeditor->Width='573';
$oFCKeditor->Height='600';
?>
```

P.S. fckeditor stores Arabic content successfully in database, problem is when I try to edit content.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: is there any security issue or permission of new php version forced editor show no Arabic content?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code after `$oFCKeditor->Value`

```
$oFCKeditor->Config['DefaultLanguage'] = 'ar';
$oFCKeditor->Config['AutoDetectLanguage'] = false;
```

**Note** If you want this to change dynamically then you should alter your approach following these [guidelines](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/language-selection-fckeditor/)